# My code wont display the Title of the inscription

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code won't display the Title of the inscription

[image]

[image]

I have been asking chat gpt for hours on end and cant get past this error

I tried adding and removing title.innerHTML = inscriptionData.title; and a changing to inscriptionDataResult
it didn't work

```js
const start = 63339;
const end = 64301;
const limit = 1000;

fetch(`https://ordapi.xyz/inscriptions/?start=${start}&end=${end}&limit=${limit}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(inscriptionData => {
    // Get the list of IDs from the text file
    fetch('ids.txt')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(ids => {
        // Split the IDs by line
        const idList = ids.split('\n');

        // Get the container for the inscription grid
        const inscriptionGrid = document.querySelector('.inscription-grid');

        // Create the HTML elements for each inscription
        idList.forEach((id, index) => {
          // Create the container div
          const containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
          containerDiv.classList.add('inscription-item');

          // Create the image container
          const imageContainer = document.createElement('div');
          imageContainer.classList.add('image-container');

          // Create the image element
          const image = document.createElement('img');
          image.src = `https://ordinals.com/content/${id}`;
          image.id = `img${index}`;
          image.classList.add(`img${index}`);

          // Create the link element
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = `../inscription?id=${id}`;
          link.id = `link${index}`;
          link.classList.add(`link${index}`);

          // Create the title element
          const title = document.createElement('title');
          title.href = `../inscription?id=${id}`;
          title.id = `title${index}`;
          title.classList.add(`title${index}`);
          title.innerHTML = inscriptionData.title;

          // Create the guid element
          const guid = document.createElement('a');
          guid.href = `../inscription?id=${id}`;
          guid.id = `guid${index}`;
          guid.classList.add(`guid${index}`);

          // Add the elements to the container
          imageContainer.appendChild(image);
          imageContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
          imageContainer.appendChild(link);
          containerDiv.appendChild(imageContainer);
          containerDiv.appendChild(title);
          containerDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          containerDiv.appendChild(guid);

          // Add the container to the inscription grid
          inscriptionGrid.appendChild(containerDiv);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching IDs:', error);
      });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  });
```

```css
.inscription-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  gap: 0.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
}

.inscription-item {
  background-color: #161718;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  width: 308.656px;
  height: 338.656px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 0.1px solid #313539;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  max-height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.inscription-item {
  background-color: #161718;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  width: 308.656px;
  height: 338.656px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 0.1px solid #313539;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  max-height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.inscription-item img {
  border: 1.5px solid #313539;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 230.656px;
  height: 230.656px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.inscription-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: -8px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.inscription-item hr {
  margin: 0;
  width: 230.656px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #313539;
}

.inscription-item .image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: "have been asking chat gpt for hours" — ChatGPT is a bullshit generator. You **cannot** expect anything it produces to be factual.

Comment: [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) vs [figcaption](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption)

Answer (score 0):

The `<title>` element is used to control the text that is:

- Displayed in the browsers title bar
- Displayed in the tab for the page
- Used as the default name for a bookmark

It is **not**, by default, rendered anywhere in the page itself and is **not** allowed anywhere except as a child element of the `<head>`.

---

To create an image with associated caption use a combination of a `<figure>`, `<img>` and `<figcaption>` element (with the latter being used for what you are currently trying to use `<title>` for).

MDN has [detailed examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure).

Comment: Should this perhaps be a comment to a typo-type close?